# I got an Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir

Tags: npm, node-modules

I am a newbie and I am trying to run `npm run-script watch` command and it gives me that error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
```

Log:

```
> scroller@1.0.0 watch C:\JOB\promocatalog\front
> webpack --mode development --progress --watch

C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:974:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\webpack.config.js:26:26)
    at Module._compile (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)
    at C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\JOB\promocatalog\front\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scroller@1.0.0 watch: `webpack --mode development --progress --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scroller@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Stepa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-08T14_34_22_349Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone help me with this?